# When are Java security "implies" functions called?

Tags: java, security, permissions

When you want to define a new type of permission, you must implement the abstract class java.security.Permission. So you need to define the implies functions. When are these functions called?

Comment: You have added the API docs, right? What part of it did you not understand? The answer to your question is there.

Answer (score 0):

So, the obvious answer is that you open your favourite IDE and ask it. There's a lot of nonsense, but also `Permissions` and `ProtectionDomain` use it in their `implies` methods.

So lets start where it's interesting and try to find out what goes on.

`AccessControlContext.checkPermission` is the interesting method if we want to know whether an acc permits a privilege. Amongst the debugging mess of `AccessControlContext.checkPermission` is a call to `ProtectionDomain.implies` (through `context[i]`). Seems reasonable, each `ProtectionDomain` "in the stack" needs to permit the permission.

`ProtectionDomain.implies` class `implies` on its `PermissionCollection`. Fair enough.

`PermissionCollection` is an abstract class, but `Permissions` is the implementation the API docs points us to. That's going to call `implies` on a `Set` of `Permission`, right? Nooo. It's creating a specialist `PermissionCollection` for each type (implementation) of `Permission`.

Specialist collections are a really hairy part of the `java.security` design. To take an example, `FilePermission.newPermissionCollection` (I wince as I type) returns a `FilePermissionCollection` (only appears in the API docs for serialisation purposes where it is unnecessary - curse you Java Serialisation). `FilePemrissionCollection.implies` is an optimisation that does not call `FilePermission.implies`, but infers its implementation.

So typically `Permission.implies` is not called at all. An optimised version form `Permission.newPermissionCollection` is used instead.

(I am not a fan of the Java 2 Security Model or libraries.)